# Как получить url сайта, если обращаться к нему через /random с редиректом на основную страницу

Tags: python, url, get

У меня есть сайт, который при обращении на /random (https://xxx.com/random) редиректит на случайную страницу типа https://xxx/view_news=8468548964.

Как через Python отправить запрос на /random и получить url случайной страницы

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import requests

url = 'http://yoursite/random'
response = requests.get(url, allow_redirects=False)
new_location = response.headers.get('Location')
```

Объяснение

Редирект — это ответ сервера с кодом 3** и новым адресов в заголовке Location. Клиент по-умолчанию, получив такой ответ, сделает следующий запрос на новый location. Чтобы этого не произошло, нужно указать `allow_redirects=False`. Затем остаётся получить `Location` из заголовков.